# AWS SageMaker GroundTruth permissions issue (can't read manifest)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to run a simple GroundTruth labeling job with a public workforce. I upload my images to S3, start creating the labeling job, generate the manifest using their tool automatically, and explicitly specify a role that most certainly has permissions on both S3 bucket (input and output) as well as full access to SageMaker. Then I create the job (standard rest of stuff -- I just wanted to be clear that I'm doing all of that).

At first, everything looks fine. All green lights, it says it's in progress, and the images are properly showing up in the bottom where the dataset is. However, after a few minutes, the status changes to Failure and I get this: `ClientError: Access Denied. Cannot access manifest file: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:<account number>:labeling-job/<job name> using roleArn: null` in the reason for failure.

I also get the error underneath (where there used to be images but now there are none):

`The specified key <job name>/manifests/output/output.manifest isn't present in the S3 bucket <output bucket>`.

I'm very confused for a couple of reasons. First of all, this is a super simple job. I'm just trying to do the most basic bounding box example I can think of. So this should be a very well-tested path. Second, I'm explicitly specifying a role arn, so I have no idea why it's saying it's null in the error message. Is this an Amazon glitch or could I be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The role must include SageMakerFullAccess and access to the S3 bucket, so it looks like you've got that covered :)

Please check that:

- the user creating the labeling job has Cognito permissions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-getting-started-step1.html
- the manifest exists and is at the right S3 location.
- the bucket is in the same region as SageMaker.
- the bucket doesn't have any bucket policy restricting access.

If that still doesn't fix it, I'd recommend opening a support ticket with the labeling job id, etc.

Julien (AWS)

Comment: Thanks Julien. How can I see which region SageMaker is in?

Comment: I don't know how to check this and I can't open a support ticket without paying for support... but I checked everything else...

Comment: If you're working with the console, the region name is in the top right corner :) You can check the bucket location with: curl -I bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com.

If this isn't your problem, then please post details to https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=285. A lot of support folks read these forums.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I ended up just recreating the buckets from scratch and giving them the same permissions and that worked... I didn't create the buckets originally so maybe there was an issue somewhere there.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug whereby sometimes the console will say something like `401 ValidationException: The specified key s3prefix/smgt-out/yourjobname/manifests/output/output.manifest isn't present in the S3 bucket yourbucket. Request ID: a08f656a-ee9a-4c9b-b412-eb609d8ce194` but that's not the actual problem.  For some reason the console is displaying the wrong error message.  If you use the API (or AWS CLI) to DescribeLabelingJob like

```
aws sagemaker describe-labeling-job --labeling-job-name yourjobname
```

you will see the actual problem.  In my case, one of the S3 files that define the UI instructions was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to write to a different bucket to the one that was used successfully before.

Apparently the IAM role ARN can be assigned permissions for a particular bucket only.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to refer to CloudWatch logs and look for a `CloudWatch>>CloudWatch Logs >> Log groups >> /aws/sagemaker/LabelingJobs` group. I had all points ticked from another post, but my pre-processing Lambda function had wrong id for my region and the error was obvious in the logs.